# somar o total em um ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

sou iniciante em angularJS e estou com o seguinte problema e não sei como resolver!

Tenho uma tabela e preciso calcular o total de residuos somando todos os preços.
Dentro de ng-repeat tem uma coluna onde apresenta todos os valores de residuos, porém não sei a sintaxe para ler esses itens da coluna e somar.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

```js
$scope.somarValores = function(){
     $scope.total = $scope.pedidos.residuoModel.preco + $scope.pedidos.residuoModel.preco
 }
```

```html
<tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="pedidosTabela in pedidos | filter: pesquisaPed"ng-click="selecionaPedido(pedidosTabela)">
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.id}}</td>   
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.data}}</td>
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.fornecedorModel.nome}}</td>
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.categoriaModel.nome}}</td>
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.residuoModel.nome}}</td>                          
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.residuoModel.status}}</td>
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.residuoModel.preco | currency}}</td>
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.residuoModel.peso}}</td>
                          <td>{{pedidosTabela.residuoModel.situac}}</td>
                          <td><label ="{{pedidosTabela.residuoModel.preco}+{{pedidosTabela.residuoModel.preco}}"/></td>  
                        </tr>               
                      </tbody>
```

```html
   <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th>Total: {{total}}</th>
                                          
                        </tr>
                      </thead> 
                      <br><br><br><br>
                  <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="somarValores()" role="button" placeholder="">Totalizadores  </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce vai precisar fazer um for para calcular tudo.

```
$scope.somarValores = function(){
    $scope.total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.pedidos.length; i++) {
       $scope.total += $scope.pedidos[i].residuoModel.preco
    }
}
```

Comment: ou um reduce: https://medium.com/@raullesteves/javascript-entendendo-o-reduce-de-uma-vez-por-todas-c4cbaa16e380

Comment: Não conhecia o reduce, me parece ser melhor que um for.

Comment: Matheus Barni Funcionou para mim!!! muito obrigado cara vc é o cara mano

Comment: Cezar obrigado também pela dica, vou testar desta forma também, um abraço!